# Marketplace Google sheets Add-on: Set up monthly payment

Tags: add-on, google-apps-marketplace, marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

We created a google sheets add-on and we are about to publish it publically.  Can someone clear this up.

I have been told 
1)  the monthly payment has to be created by us, the developer but

2) I also have heard that google changed payment structure requiring us to run all monthly payments through google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The G Suite Marketplace does not have a built-in payment solution.

Comment: Great that means we can use 3rd party payment solution!